# How to bind this for scheduled job inside class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to implement a scheduled queue handler inside my class with `node-schedule`.

But the callback has the scope of the different class and doesn't have access to the object members with `this`. Any suggestions how to make it work?

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

class QueueHandler {
  constructor() {
    this.queue = [];
    this.j = schedule.scheduleJob('send', '*/10 * * * * *', this.parseNext);
    this.sendJob = schedule.scheduledJobs['send'];
  }

  // this one called from outside
  fillQueue(rows) {
    rows.forEach(user => {
      this.queue.push(user);
    });
  }

  parseNext() {
    if (this.queue.length > 0) {  // here comes the problem - this.queue undefined
      const next = this.queue.shift();
      // do some manipulations with the next item
    } else {
      console.log('empty queue');
    }
  }
}

module.exports.QueueHandler = QueueHandler;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in your question, you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```
this.j = schedule.scheduleJob('send', '*/10 * * * * *', this.parseNext.bind(this));
```

Or you can use [arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
schedule.scheduleJob('send', '*/10 * * * * *', x=>this.parseNext(x));
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfect. I don't know why, but it didn't work first time I tried it before posting a question. Possibly some typo.